# Managing a QStringList-based model from the QML side

Tags: qt, list, qml, qstring

I can expose a QStringList-based model from C++ side to QML [as explained here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qstringlist-based-model)

How can I modify it the QStringList-based model from the QML side (insert new items, delete them)? Are some functions of `QStringListModel` or `QStringList` available to be called from QML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Qt documentation :

> Any method of a QObject-derived type is accessible from QML code if it
>   is:
>
> ```
> A public method flagged with the Q_INVOKABLE() macro
> A method that is a public Qt slot
> ```

You can have a manager class which is derived from `QObject` and expose it to QML. Then you can implement the desired functionalities in the manager and access it from the QML side :

```
class StringListManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void append (QString str) 
    { 
        m_list.append(str); 
    }


private:
    QStringList m_list;
};
```

Also an instance of `StringListManager` should be set as the context data for your qml file:

```
QQmlEngine engine;
StringListManager manager;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("manager", &manager);
```

Now you can access the the functions of the manager class from QML side :

```
onClicked: {
    manager.append("From QML");
}
```

Comment: And why can't one manage the model as a JS array? The doc says that QStringList is represented as an array http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#sequence-type-to-javascript-array